# setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using WebSocket to communicate with my server and on my `handleSubmit()` function I am entering some value and on the basis of that I am communicating with server and update my state as what the data is recieved from the ws.
So, for the first time , everything is working fine.

On `componentWillUnmount` also I am communicating with websocket and sending an action to stop sending me data. But when I again try to communicate with websocket I update my state and get the following error

```
Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the UserData component.
```

Below is the code

```
 class UserData extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      labelMsg: "",
      showUsr: false,
      deviceDetails: [],
      center: {lat: 20.5837, lng: 78.9629},
      zoom: 5,
      devData: {
          mainPower: "",
          relayState: "",
          motion: "",
          ang: 0,
          lat: 20.5837,
          lng: 78.9629,
          spd: 0
      },
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    global.gWebSocket.SendRequest({
      data: { a: "getDevLoc" , d: {idx:1} },
      cb: (d)=> {
        this.setState({
         devData: d.obj,
          center: {lat: d.obj.lat, lng:d.obj.lng}
        })
        console.log("---> ", d.obj);
      }
    })
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
  global.gWebSocket.SendRequest({
    data: { a: "stopDevLoc" , d: {idx:1} },
    cb: (d)=> {
      console.log("--->", d.obj);
    }
  })
}


  render(){
    var byRegNum = <input type="text" className="form-control text-uppercase" id="name" onChange={this.byRegNo}/>;
    var byHandle = <input type="text" className="form-control" id="handle" onChange={(e)=> this.handle = e.target.value}/>;
    var byMobile = <input type="number" className="form-control" id="mobile" onChange={(e)=> this.number = e.target.value}/>;
    var byEmail = <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" onChange={(e)=> this.email = e.target.value}/>;
    return(
      <div className="col-lg-12">
        <div className="container">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="submit">
            {this.Search("By Registration Number",byRegNum)}
            {this.Search("By User Handle",byHandle)}
            {this.Search("By Mobile Number",byMobile)}
            {this.Search("By Email",byEmail)}
            <div className="text-center">
              <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Search"/>
              <label>{this.state.labelMsg} </label>
            </div>
          </form>
      )
   }
 }
```

I don't know what I am missing or what I am doing wrong. Please help me with this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically your callback is starting before it's unmounted, and finishing after, so when it gets to `this.setState` it's already unmounted.

The easiest way to fix this is to keep track of when the component is mounted/unmounted. There was previously a method in React to do this for you, but [now it's recommended to handle this yourself](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

Here you can set `this._isMounted` yourself in the `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`, and then only call `setState` when it's set:

```
class UserData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      labelMsg: "",
      showUsr: false,
      deviceDetails: [],
      center: {lat: 20.5837, lng: 78.9629},
      zoom: 5,
      devData: {
          mainPower: "",
          relayState: "",
          motion: "",
          ang: 0,
          lat: 20.5837,
          lng: 78.9629,
          spd: 0
      },
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    global.gWebSocket.SendRequest({
      data: { a: "getDevLoc" , d: {idx:1} },
      cb: (d) => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
          this.setState({
            devData: d.obj,
            center: {lat: d.obj.lat, lng:d.obj.lng}
          });
          console.log("---> ", d.obj);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
    global.gWebSocket.SendRequest({
      data: { a: "stopDevLoc" , d: {idx:1} },
      cb: (d) => {
        console.log("--->", d.obj);
      }
    });
  }
```

There are some other ways to fix this problem as well, but they would require more refactoring.

Comment: Actually It was a problem with my websocket. Problem wasn't in the above code. The websocket was recieving a callback from the server and I made a check that It only sends a callback to the client when the client sends the msg to server. So at 1st time my client sends the msg to server and server sends the corresponding message to client. But after that, my server already sends some message to client but client dosen't recieves it. It re-requests the server. Which fails here. :)